# run and jump and return to running SpriteKit Swift

Tags: xcode, swift3, sprite-kit, action, game-physics

I'm new to programming with SpriteKit and Swift. I have followed a few tutorials, but I'm now stucking for a couple of days.

- i have multiple animations in an separate Actions file, "idle", "run" and jump. When my games start you see the idle figure and when you tap it will move from idle animation to the running animation. So far so good. But when my figure start jumping with next tap, the running animation is also still on my screen. When the jumps finish the jump animation is gone. How can I remove the running animation for a second?

So far the only other option I've got is to remove also the running animation as the jump animation. They won't comeback.

This is my hero file where if have the actions for running and jumping:

```
func runPlayer(){

        let playerRun:SKAction = SKAction(named: "run", duration: moveSpeed)!
        let runAction:SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, duration: moveSpeed)
        let runGroup:SKAction = SKAction.group([playerRun, runAction])
        thePlayerRuns.run(runGroup, withKey: "run")
        thePlayerRuns.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        thePlayerRuns.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0)
        thePlayerRuns.size = CGSize(width: 160.25, height: 135.55)
        thePlayerRuns.zPosition = 99

        addChild(thePlayerRuns)

    }

    func jumpPlayer(){

        let playerJump: SKAction = SKAction(named: "jump", duration: moveSpeed)!
        let jumpUp: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 50, duration: 0.5)
        let jumpDown: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -80, duration: 0.5)
        let jumpSeq: SKAction = SKAction.sequence([jumpUp, jumpDown])
        let jumpGroup: SKAction = SKAction.group([playerJump, jumpSeq])
        thePlayerJumps.run(jumpGroup, withKey: "jump")
        thePlayerJumps.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        thePlayerJumps.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        thePlayerJumps.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        thePlayerJumps.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 30)
        thePlayerJumps.size = CGSize(width: 160.25, height: 135.55)
        thePlayerJumps.zPosition = 99
        addChild(thePlayerJumps)

        thePlayerRuns.removeFromParent()


        thePlayerJumps.run(
            SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0),SKAction.removeFromParent()])
        )

//        thePlayerRuns.run(
//            SKAction.sequence([SKAction.removeFromParent()])
//            
//        )

        let otherWait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
        let otherSequence = SKAction.sequence([otherWait, SKAction(runPlayer())])
        run(otherSequence)

        /*
        let otherWait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
        let otherSequence = SKAction.sequence([otherWait, SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)])
        runAction(otherSequence)
        */
    }
```

And this is my Gamescene:

```
hero = MTHero()

    hero.position = CGPoint(x: 70, y: 278)

    addChild(hero)
    hero.idlePlayer()

}


func start(){

    isStarted = true
    hero.stop()
    movingGround.start()
    hero.runPlayer()

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if !isStarted {
        start()
    }else{
        hero.jumpPlayer()
    }

    }

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered


}
```

I thing I have to do something in thouchesBagan with another else statement.

Thanks in advance! Moi

Comment: Extra info: my runaction in the Actions.sks file is an repeatForever. Could that be the problem? If so, how can I start with the first tap to run, tap again to jump and when the character lands run again (with tapping, the next tap should initialize a jump)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve it. I'm not sure that it is the best option. But in my jumpPlayer function I have added the following code:

```
self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)) {
        self.addChild(self.thePlayerRuns)
```

just under

```
thePlayerJumps.run(
        SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0),SKAction.removeFromParent()])
    )
```

If you have suggestion for a better solution, please let me know.